# Почему в JS 1.65 - 1 =  0.6499999999999999

Tags: javascript

или `1.85 - 1 = 0.8500000000000001`.

А числа больше двух уже имеют только два знака после запятой

```
2.65 - 1 = 1,65
2.85 - 1 = 1,85
```

Comment: @Fike спасибо, только я сначала испугался что на **floating-point-gui.de** только на немецком

Comment: Там не объяснено про числа больше двух.

Comment: @knes `It’s not stupid, just different`

Comment: это про 0,5 и 0,3.

Хотя...
>>> 1.65 - 1
0.6499999999999999
>>> 2.65 - 1
1.65
>>> 2.13 - 1
1.13
>>> 2.131 - 1
1.1309999999999998
>>> 20.131 - 1
19.131

Гм. Ну да, прально. У двойки лишний разряд появляется, чтобы эту фигню отобразить.

Comment: Это особенность хранения чисел с плавающей запятой в двоичном виде. Сбой в точности происходит если число не раскладывается на сумму степеней двойки.

Comment: В общем. Юзаем принудительное округление.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Basic Answers](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

- Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?
- Why do computers use such a stupid system?
- What can I do to avoid this problem?
- Why do other calculations like 0.1 + 0.4 work correctly?

Comment: @Fike тогда только так `Math.round((1.65 - 1) * 100) / 100` ?

Comment: Лучше 

    function rnd(num,signs){
      signs = Math.pow(10,Math.round(signs));
      return Math.round(num*signs)/signs;
    }

чтобы не было хардкода.

Comment: @Etki, ответ ссылка!

Comment: @Visman сейчас физически по времени не смогу переписать с полной теоретической выкладкой.